# What causes dead zones on digitizer?

Tags: touchscreen

I ordered a replacement digitizer after I cracked the old one. I installed the replacement, and it looks fine. But it has large horizontal bands across it that do not register touch, rendering the phone very difficult to use.

I was hoping someone has some experience in this area to share. Are there any tips or tricks that can resolve this problem, or is it likely I've gotten a defective digitizer?

Comment: I have the same issue, was it the digitizer? Did the new lcd fix the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had this issue recently. I only had one, vertical band, but it still affected use, mostly typing. I demonstrated the issue (seen below) and contacted the [ebay] seller. They promptly classified it as defective and sent me a new one. This will most likely be the solution to your problem as well. As I did, I would use a drawing program to verify, and inquire about a replacement screen and digitizer.

[image: You see that on the right site the lines are edgy]